# How to localize built-in BitRock variables

Tags: bitrock

I'm trying to localize built-in BitRock variables. I need an English and a Spanish version. Unfortunately Yes and No buttons don't get translated automatically when picking a different language for the installer.

I found a solution in the documentation. There is a list of built in variables:

https://clients.bitrock.com/installbuilder/docs/en.lng

These can be overwritten in own language files.

I tried the following:

Spanish language file:

```
Installer.Button.Yes=&Sí
Installer.Button.No=&No
```

English language file:

```
Installer.Button.Yes=&Yes
Installer.Button.No=&No
```

When rebuilding my installer, I'm still getting the non-localized English Yes and No texts on the corresponding buttons. 
The language file seems to be added properly to the installer project, because the other translations appear well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lengthy investigation i figured out, that the installer generated by the BitRock InstallBuilder is using the native dialogs of the OS when installer used in MacOS or Windows. This means, that whatever your OS's native language is, the Message Dialog button texts will be translated to that language, no matter what language you picked for the installation process.

Although this can not be modified by using the regular InstallBuilder, InstallBuilder for Qt can force translate these texts too.

https://support.bitrock.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115002746729-Question-dialog-ignore-language-selection

Meanwhile I received a response from BitRock Support too, which confirms the above:

> InstallBuilder uses native operating system for showing questions in
>   many cases, which would cause the language of the buttons to be the
>   native language of the operating system, not the one of installer.
>   This is the case on Windows for example. In most cases it is not
>   possible to translate the buttons as they are not controlled by
>   InstallBuilder. What operating system is this happening on? In most
>   cases the end user will have their native language set as the primary
>   language of the operating system and the buttons will show their
>   native text. Could you try changing the primary display language of
>   the operating system to see if the text of the buttons changes?